# How to see URL is returning an Image Response in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, scrapy

I am trying to write an webscraper with scrapy. I am actually hitting the AJAX response, Where I do not get the exact image address but I have to make that link by concatenating its part from the data. but the problem is website is having three different kinds of images lets say
`www.something.com/user/scale_128.jpg` , `www.something.com/user/scale_256.jpg` `www.something.com/user/scale_512.jpg`

Now I am having a list with `scales = [512, 256, 128]`. I make a link with them.

```
scales = ['512', '256', '128']
    for scale in scales:
        image_url = base_url.format(image_id, scale)
        image_data= scrapy.http.Response(image_url)
        print(image_data.status)
        if image_data.status == 200:
            image.add_value("url", image_url)
            image.add_value("image", image_url)
```

This is not working because each link returns and XML document with 200 status code (It is confirmed that at least 1 is an actual image) . I want to check which link sent me image in response. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Most file formats (binary ones, like JPEG, in particular) have "magic numbers" associated with them. A magic number is a few bytes at the start of the file, that have a known, constant value, associated with a file type. JPEG happens to have multiple such magic numbers, which you can find in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures).

So, you simply need to look at the returned data (in binary form), and compare the first few byte of it against the different JPEG magic numbers.